# How to get coordinates of a path from svg on a website into R

Tags: html, r, svg

I am trying to import [an online SVG map](https://dce2015.thestandnews.com) into R, to see if I can reproduce the results in R.

First, I can download the html code of the SVGs using the following code:

```
svg <- html("https://dce2015.thestandnews.com") %>% html_nodes("g")
```

and further use

```
... %>% html_nodes("polygon") %>% html_attr("points")
... %>% html_nodes("polyline") %>% html_attr("points")
... %>% html_nodes("path") %>% html_attr("d")
```

to get the coordinates in a character strings.

I am able to deal with `<polygon ...>` and `<polyline ...>` but when I try to extract the coordinates inside `<path ...>`, I find there are so many curve command (e.g. `s`, `S`, `c` etc). Is there any method get some smoothed points lying on the curve?

Also, is there any more elegant way to import online SVG in R as polygons?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You would be *much* better off trying to find an actual shapefile of the electoral districts (I didn't really try to find one but a quick google suggested that it does exist). However, this was an interesting idea.

I think it'd be ultimately cool to port [svg-to-wkt](https://github.com/davidmcclure/svg-to-wkt) to R from DOM-javascript. But, if this is a one-off solution then you can do something like:

```
library(rvest)
library(rgeos)

URL <- "https://dce2015.thestandnews.com/"
pg <- read_html(URL)
svg_map <- html_nodes(pg, "svg#hkmap")
writeLines(as.character(svg_map), "hk.txt")

# use http://svg-to-wkt.linfiniti.com/ with svg from hk.txt
# saving it to hk.wkt

wkt_txt <- paste0(readLines("hk.wkt"), sep="", collapse="")
svg_wkt <- readWKT(wkt_txt)
```

`svg_wkt` is a `SpatialCollections` object that won't work with ggplot2. But, most of the SVG got converted to polygons:

```
plot(svg_wkt@polyobj)
```

[image]

Note that there *are* some elements in `svg_wkt@lineobj` (which you would run into even if you did a full conversion in R IMO). Those will need to be dealt with.

You can pass in IDs to `readWKT` in order to have some hope of being able to more with this in R (i.e. plot the election data it seems you want to plot) but I have to go back to my original suggestion of advocating the use of a proper shapefile if you really do want to plot the election data.

Comment: Thanks. I do have a shapefile, but the polygons of the areas along the sea shore cover the sea area, which is not wanted by me. That's why I want to download these SVGs when I see it. However, I noticed that a few districts are missing in your plot. Do you know any possible reason?

Comment: Also,` as.character(svg_map)` return me `"<pointer: 0x0000000014fefb30>"`